# Cors block while trying to get Instagram access token on client side using react/js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, facebook, instagram, instagram-api

Okay so im trying to get access token im following the main guide provided by facebook app developers which is: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/getting-started. Im at **step: 5**, where i try to exchange my code for access_token. I do post request to https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token however i get cors blocked with this error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token' from origin
> 'https://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header
> field content-type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in
> preflight response.

I literlly tried everything. Adding headers to axios, using ngrok to get an actual secure https: and not self made cert (for dev mode ofc). I also changed the app ouath urls. What could the problem be?

Comment: Have you explored developer settings to add permissions / allowed URLs for your app? Try and adding localhost there

Comment: Have you tried: `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token`

Comment: This endpoint is not CORS-enabled, because you are not supposed to make calls to it from the client side to begin with. The request requires your app secret - and that should never be exposed in client-side code; anyone could steal it from there, and with that and your app id, they would automatically have a valid app access token for your app.

Comment: Yea that's probably 100% times better i did that so my secret is safe on the server.. But jeez you don't  have to down vote ..

Answer (score 0):

Yeap i allowed urls i did everything. I tried https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token it didn't work, it says bad request. However i managed to solve it with an extra library called **axios-oauth-client**: **https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios-oauth-client**. After implementing this library and instead of doing axios.post(url, data) but using this library and passing the data in there everything works fine and i get the access token. Something with the headers might have been the problem